# Response.write line of code in button click event handler is executed on page load

Tags: asp.net

I have some javascript on an asp.net page code behind, but whenever the page loads, the code (response.write, and in an asp.net button click event handler), is fired.

Is this a bug? I want to only fire that response.write line of code obviously when the button is clicked, not on the page's load. How could I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you show some code? Your problem description is a little abstract.

Comment: Post the code of the event handler and page load event handler. Do you call the event handler in the page load event handler?

Comment: Code snippet will help us to understand the problem. Please post some

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to rethink you approach completely. The way that you tried is impossible because the code doesn't run in that order.

This is how a page is created:

1. The browser sends the request to the server.
2. The ASP.NET code runs on the server to create the page source.
3. The page source is sent to the browser.
4. The browser parses the page source and creates a DOM tree and Javascript executables from it.
5. The browser shows the page and runs the Javscript code.

The `Response.Write` happens in step 2, and the button click happens after step 5, so you would need a [TARDIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TARDIS) to make the click affect how the page is created.